# Is there a way I can display question choices for a multiple choice quiz program

Tags: python

```
def sample_questions():
    correct = 0
    incorrect = 0

    question_list = [
        {
            "question": "Question 1: Example question? ",
            "answer": "Example correct choice:",
            "choices": ["1: Example choice1.", "2:  Example choice2.", "3:  Example choice3.", "4: Example choice4."]
        },
        {
            "question": "Question 2: Example question number 2 ?: ",
            "answer": "Example correct choice",
            "choices": ["1: Example choice1.", "2:  Example choice2.", "3:  Example choice3.", "4: Example choice4."]
        }

if sample_questions == "sample"
 sample_questions
```

I am trying to create a quiz in Python using dictionaries. Is there a way I can display the "choices" the user can enter on the screen?

Expected output:

This is a sample question?
#answer is number 1

1: yes 2: no 3: maybe 4:ok

Correct! 1 is the right answer!

Comment: Yes, definitely there _is_ a way. Let us know if you get stuck trying to figure out _how_.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it. First you need to save the right answer (the number of it) as anwser like this (if the answer is 1):

```
{
"question": "Question 1: Example question? ",
"answer": 1,
"choices": ["1: Example choice1.", "2:  Example choice2.", "3:  Example choice3.", "4: Example choice4."]
}
```

1. print question
2. print choices with for loop
3. save input of user
4. proof if the answer is correct

```
i = 0 #indicates which question

question = question_list[i]["question"]
print(question)

choices = question_list[i]["choices"]
print(choices)

answer = question_list[i]["answer"]
user_answer = input("Your Answer: ")
if answer == user_answer:
    print("Correct! " + str(answer) + " is the right answer!")
else: print("Wrong! " + str(answer) + " is the right answer!")
```